# Objectify entity relationship

Tags: android, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm beginner in Android and I'm trying to understand how GAE works with Objectify.

So I've created two classes, one 'User' and another one 'Journey'. Each Journey belongs to a User.

User Class

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Index private String mac;
    private String name;
    private String firstName;
    private Long age;
    private String email;
    private String password;
// Getters and setters
}
```

Journey Class

```
@Entity
public class Journey {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    Key<User> driver;
    private Event event;
    private Long nbPlaces;
    private String departureTime;
    private String destination;
}
```

1. I've writed the following method on the User class, is this correct ?

   @Transient
   Key getKey() {
       return Key.create(User.class, id);
   }
2. How can I set the Key of the User in my Journey Object ? (I think I can't use a simple setter.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously declared:

```
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
```

To get the object:

```
public User get(Long id) {
     return ofy().load().key(Key.create(User.class, id)).now();
}
```

And to set the Key from `User` into `Journey` class, you need to pass into the constructor when the object is created, or get the object `Journey` set the parameters and save it. But you need to get the Key previously:

```
public Long getKey(User user) {
     Key<User> generatedKey = ofy().save().entity(user).now();
     return generatedKey.getId();
}
```

After this, you can attach a list of `Users` into `Journey`class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't know where I've to paste this code. In the Entity or in the Endpoint ?
Sorry but I'm neewbie.

Comment: In your Endpoint. Here more information useful for you: https://rominirani.com/android-studio-cloud-endpoints-objectify-persistence-76b26c13bb2a#.mwuiaz7st

Comment: Ok, so I've to override the generated get method into the User Endpoint with the first code you've writed right ?
Where I've to write the second part of code ? I can't put this method into an Endpoint because an Endpoint method can't return a primitive type..

Comment: For your first question the answer is yes. The second part only returns the Key generated for that User object, so you can change the primitive type to long. It was not clear for me how you can save the reference from User into Journey, but you can implement it in different ways once you get an object or returns the Key correctly.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer :-)
How can I contact you directly to speak about this ?